# Remove the http protocol from images

Tags: images, urls, ssl, http

I've been banging my head on the wall trying to filter my posts to remove the http: protocol from the img src and I think I may have found a solution. Does anybody see anything wrong with this solution within the loop:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = str_replace(array('http:', 'https:'), '', $content);

echo $content
```

Comment: This could cause issues with 3rd party URLs in hyperlinks not running https

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you provided could cause issues with 3rd party URLs in hyperlinks not running https. You can fix this by including your home url, e.g:

```
$content = str_replace( set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'http' ), set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'relative' ), $content);
```

Next, you're applying this when you'd like to display the content, which means you need to do an additional step. Namely, you need to apply a filter called `the_content` which does some final processing, such as creating paragraphs etc:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = str_replace( set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'http' ), set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'relative' ), $content);
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );

echo $content
```

Finally, for maximum compatibility, just call `the_content();`, and use the `the_content` filter to do your modification:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'brandozz_url_filter' );

function brandozz_url_filter( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace( set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'http' ), set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'relative' ), $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Filters and hooks can go inside a plugin or `functions.php`, this is what it looks like as a plugin:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Relative local URLs
 * Plugin URI:        http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174228/remove-the-http-protocol-from-images
 * Description:       Replaces http:// URL containing the home url, with relative protocol urls 
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            Tom J Nowell
 * Author URI:        http://tomjn.com/
 */

add_filter( 'the_content', 'tomjn_filter_relative_content_urls' );

function tomjn_filter_relative_content_urls( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace( set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'http' ), set_url_scheme( home_url(), 'relative' ), $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: All of the plugins and solutions out there to handle this sort of thing seemed to be so heavy and labor intensive. I figured that there had to be a simpler solution. Thank you for your help and explaining each solution above.

Comment: Now if you put a plugin header comment at the top of a file, and that code snippet at the end, you'll have a super lightweight plugin! I may do just that

Comment: You should, I've implemented it on my end and it works great.